# vertical-align text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some *really* basic HTML & CSS:

```css
header {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Hello, World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    Hello<sup>World</sup>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

But the text doesn't get aligned in the middle. Why not?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property only applies to:

> inline-level and 'table-cell' elements

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

You could use [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) to vertically center the text, just make it bigger than the actual `font-size`, however it is only effective if the text spans a single line.

Alternatively you could add `padding` to the top and bottom of the `header` element by equal values.

Edited as per comment: the obvious solution if using HTML5 `header` element would be to make it `display: table-cell;` instead of the default block which I think the reset CSS's apply.

Comment: I'm going to put a lot more into the header though (think navigation, search, etc.). Will I need to put the text in a separate container?

Comment: no you shouldn't need a separate div/container, just pad the header evenly top and bottom

Comment: @clairesuzy: That doesn't make sense. Imagine I had to differently-sized texts in the header and wanted to align them in the middle. I could never achieve that with padding, could I?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion - you pad the `header` itself, the scenario you describe lends itself to the fact you will actually have more divs/elements to contain the nav, search etc the.. however the clue is in my answer make the header `display: table-cell;`

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to take advantage of the `table-cell` display property, which will make vertical align work. I'm sorry I was stuck in one line text mode but re:comment above yes you would need the extra elements inside the header to get the best from padding, though I was presuming you had them  when you mentioned your different elements :o

Comment: @clairesuzy: Unfortunately, using `display: table-cell;` messes up the width property. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: does giving it a 100% width, like the block element display would have had not help?.. actually don't think it does :( needs to be part of a table.. hang on

Comment: OK a "table-cell" needs to be part of "table" (even is CSS display terms apparently ;)) - so in order to make it take the 100% width - you can either make the body element `display-table; width: 100%` too or if you've a "wrapper" div do it on there, making a container element `display: table` shouldn't affect things adversely, in fact it can have benefits like full length columns but YMMV

Comment: Unfortunately, neither `table-cell` nor 'inline-level' works

Answer (score 25):

Flexbox can do this pretty easily now:

```
header {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waYBjv

Comment: this is not vertical alignment, this is horizontal alignment

Comment: This is better option then `display: table-cell;`.

Answer (score 11):

Try this, work very well for me:

```
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:center;
-ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my favorite trick for vertical aligning things it uses flex box, everything should use flex box!

```css
header {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: black solid 0.1rem;
    height: 200px; <!--Insert any height -->
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            Hello<sup>World</sup>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `vertical-align` attribute is for inline elements only. It will have no effect on block level elements, like a div or a paragraph.If you would like to vertically align an inline element to the middle just use this.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Check out more here : [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: I found that the simplest solution was to enclose my text in a paragraph tag to which I apply a CSS style that set the top margin. While this requires a separate selector for each of the six containers that I have arrayed in two rows, three abreast, it gets the job done without too much fuss.

Answer (score 3):

`vertical-align` doesn't work the way you think it does in elements with `display:block`. People usually just use, for example, `line-height:60px` if the text is the only thing in the element and all stays on the same line.

If more stuff is going in there, it's probably better to give the container a height if you absolutely must and tweak the margin/padding/etc. of elements inside the containing element until it looks right.

Comment: Well, there's going to be a lot more in the header in the end (navigation and stuff). So using `line-height` is not a possibility.

Comment: I can't put the text inside a `div` and `vertical-align: middle` that `div` though since `div`s aren't inline, right? What's a good workaround (sorry for the dumb questions, I'm very new to HTML/CSS).

Comment: Without knowing what other elements are going to be inside `<header>`, their positions and how it all should look, there's no good answer I can give you.

Comment: Basically it's a bar stretching over the entire screen. I got some text and some buttons in the bar. All those elements should be vertically-aligned to the middle. A lot like the top bar here at Stack Overflow, really.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a table you can use vertical-align:middle and display:inline-block while using an empty inline element with 100% height:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycugZ/

```
<!DOCTYPE><html><body> <!-- Author: brillout.com -->

<div style='height: 300px;border: 1px solid black;text-align:center'>
  <div class='i'>vertical-align + inline-block<br>trick<br>in action</div>
  <div class='i' style='height:100%;width:0px'></div>
</div>
<style> div.i{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle } </style>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;height:200px;position: relative;">
     <div style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left:50%;">
     hello mahesh 
     </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0dmh3ac3/)

Try this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the text is not in the true center. The top-left corner of the text "box" is now in the center.