# CSS Div with Left and Right Text with a Margin and Vertically Aligned

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, margins

I am trying to create a `div` with left and right aligned text. The left text is a larger font that the right. I would like to have a margin (10px) to the left of the left text and to the right of the right text. What I am getting is:

```
+------------------------------+
|                         Right|
|Left                          |
+------------------------------+
```

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<div id='banner'>
  <p class='align-left banner-text-large'>Left</p>
  <p class='align-right banner-text-small'>Right</p>
</div>

#banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #702f7b;
  clear: both;
}

.banner-text-large {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.banner-text-small {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.align-left {
  float: left;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should you be using <span> instead of <p> in the banner div? The <p> is what is making the text appear on different lines.

Comment: Are the `p` elements meant to be on the same horizontal line?

Comment: The `p` elements are supposed to be on the same line. I got that from another web site (not sure where).

Comment: @DOK: When I changed it to `span`, the text moved to the top of the banner `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the `p` elements vertically-centered within their parent, simply set `line-height` equal to the height of the parent element. To have them *also* `10px` away from the left, and right, sides of their parent set the `padding-left` and `padding-right` on that parent element.

That said, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
#banner {
    /* above CSS unchanged */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* forces the width of the element
                               to include the padding and border widths */
    padding: 0 10px; /* sets the padding-top and padding-bottom to 0,
                        padding-left and padding-right to 10px */
}

#banner p {
    margin: 0; /* overrides the browser default-margin */
    padding: 0; /* overrides the browser default-padding */
    line-height: 50px; /* forces the text to be vertically centred */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TDq2F/2/).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've not reset the default margin on the paragraph element

just add this to your css (and add the extra margins into the left and right aligned text):

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

here's a jsfiddle to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/benbroadley88/5C4Eb/

Edit: and your missing the ' as mentioned in one of the comments above.

Comment: That solved part of my problem: the text has left and right margins. The text is still not vertically aligning. As I understand it, `vertical-align: middle;` should place the vertical center of the text in the center of its parent container.

Comment: It only aligns the text inside the specified element. You should set it to the container of both elements you want to align. But also notice: it won't work on float element.

Comment: the reason that vertical-align doesn't work is that it only applies to table elements, you might want to have a read through the answers to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442226/css-vertical-align-not-working

Comment: It also applies to [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<div id='banner'>
  <p class='align-left banner-text-large'>Left</p>
  <p class='align-right banner-text-small'>RIGHT</p>
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
    }

 #banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #702f7b;
  clear: both;
}

.banner-text-large {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.banner-text-small {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'arial';
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.align-left {
  float: left;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin of `<p>` comes from broswer's style sheet. 
Override the margin of `p`, and set `line-height` to the same value for both.

http://jsfiddle.net/wJyv2/1/

```
<div id='banner'>
  <p class='align-left banner-text banner-text-large'>Left</p>
  <p class='align-right banner-text banner-text-small'>RIGHT</p>
</div>

.banner-text {
  margin: 15px 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.banner-text-large {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.banner-text-small {
  font-size: 14px;  
}
```