# How to set middle vertical align of elements in div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create horizontal menu in html+css, but I have problem with vertical aligment of menu element. Do you know how to center in vertial my links ?
This is code:
HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">

    <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link<br>1</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link2</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link3</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link4</a></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px #555555;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0
}

.nav
{

    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;

}

.nav a
{
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

It looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCTye.png)

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442226/css-vertical-align-not-working help?

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height` to `.nav` and get rid of `vertical-align`.

[Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/u2rL2tw1/)

```
.nav
{

    display:inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 100px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to get the text labels vertically centered without specify the line-height to be the height of the containing element.

Apply `display: table-cell` to the links (`.nav a`) and inherit the height value
first into the `.nav` and then into `.nav a`.  For table cells, the the vertical-align property will center the text as expected. The advantage of this approach is that if a label spans two lines, the text is still vertically centered.

A consequence is that the `a` has a larger active area and behaves more like a
button.  That may be a desirable feature is some designs.

Of course, is your labels are single words (one line of text only) then the
line-height trick may be a good option.

```css
#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px #555555;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.nav a {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link1<br>sub-text</a></div>
  <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link2</a></div>
  <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link3</a></div>
  <div class="nav"><a href="#">Link4</a></div>
</div>
```